# How to redirect to previous page using react-router-dom v6 from a page action() handler?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom@6.11.2 and have several pages.  User navigates from one page to another. The second page contains a pure functional form component that has both a react-router loader() and a submission action().  User fills out the form, clicks save, the action() function is called which saves the data to API, and then returns redirect("..") to navigate back to the previous page, but what React Router does is navigate back to the main page "/" instead.

In their API documentation on redirect() it does not say how to navigate back, only forwards:

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect

Here is a simplified version of my form's action() function.

```
    /** submit POST for add/update */
    export async function action({ request, params }) {
       const formData = await request.formData();
       const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    
       // call API, blah blah
    
       return redirect("..");
    }
```

What is the official way to handle this?

Comment: You probably can look into the request what path it came from and use that rather than `..`. Assuming you actually want to go to the previous page and not strictly "upwards" in hierarchy.

Comment: `".."` only removes a path segment, it doesn't issue a back navigation, e.g. a POP action, nor does it navigate to any previous location. You'll need to forward a "referrer" to the action/loader function that can provide the target path to redirect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a code snippet for you, Hope it helps!

```js
export async function action({ request }) {
  // Get data from the form.
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const email = formData.get("email");
  const password = formData.get("password");

  try {
    const logInResponse = await loginUser({ email, password }); // Your API.
    return logInResponse; // send a response.
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error: error.message,
    };
  }
}

export default function Login() {
  const location = useLocation(); // Catch ref page.
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // Redirect to page.
  const actionData = useActionData(); // Catch action function.

  const userFrom = location.state?.from || "/";

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (actionData?.accessToken) {
      navigate(userFrom, {
        replace: true,
      });
    }
  }, [actionData]); // If the action function works.

  return (<h1>LoginPage</h1>);
}
```

If you're curious about how it works, you can take a look at [this repository](https://github.com/emrecoban/caption-meow).

Comment: I'm trying this, but now when the form page is rendered I'm getting this:
react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_26__.useActionData() is undefined.    I've restarted, not getting any compile errors, etc.

import { useActionData } from "react-router-dom";
.......
const formSubmitted = useActionData();

Comment: Hey @jn4! Did you import the `useActionData` hook like this: `import { useActionData } from "react-router-dom";`?

Comment: Yes, it is imported properly.  Very strange.

Comment: It seems like the issue is occurring elsewhere. Could you try to display the `action` function response in the function?

Comment: I completed shutdown browser and IDE, and restarted fresh, and now it's not getting the webpack error.  But I'm gettong "/" for location from, so I'm debugging that next :-\

Comment: location.state is null        Do I need to pass my previous page location as state in the navigate() call ?  I would have thought that react-router would keep track of that for me.

Comment: At this point, `const userFrom = location.state?.from || "/";` if `location.state` doesn't exist, it redirects `/`.

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the delay. I've forgot that, it was an old project.